# Can deep learning determine if two samples of handwriting are by the same person?

Tags: python, deep-learning, ocr, tesseract, faster-rcnn

I have dabbled using Tesseract CNN OCR on handwriting records before and was surprised by the accuracy. I am wondering, is it possible to use it, or something else, to determine if a sample of handwriting is written by the same person?

I have searched for solutions but it is difficult to get results for anything but OCR recognition with handwriting.

Comment: I'd imagine so. Unfortunately, as this question isn't actually about coding, it's off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Gotcha. Would you recommend another platform it would be more appropriate for? I am sure I will have coding question but for now I need to know what term to even search.

Comment: "Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization." https://stats.stackexchange.com/